# Are smurf accounts allowed in Smite

Tags: smite

I know there are complaints of many smurf accounts at low levels, but are they technically allowed? Are there any instances of people being banned for using smurf accounts?

Comment: Unless stated in their Terms of Service, End User License Agreement or any other terms or license you agree to for Smite, which I never saw or heard of in any games so far, they are allowed.

Comment: Sadly, with things like the Tyr Sock Puppet Skin, smurfing is almost encouraged, as to unlock it you need to refer 3 other people who all made it to Smite lvl 15

Comment: @TheFaster it's called refer-a-friend for a reason ;)

Comment: @gruntswilldie Yes, but referring 3 friends that all have to reach lvl 15 is overkill. Not only do you have to find 3 people who would be interested in Smite, but then babysit them and make them play 20-30 hours. Making smurfs is way easier.

Comment: Smurf accounts are everywhere, the problem is when people do bad stuff with them. For example, there is people throwing games in competitive Overwatch (common stuff in South America).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smurfing is not illegal, it is not against the [Terms of Service](http://www.hirezstudios.com/docs/default-source/default-document-library/hi-rez-studios-online-terms-of-service-and-use-agreement.txt?sfvrsn=2) of Smite.
However, it is frowned upon by the community, not only in Smite but in many other games because of the huge advantage an experienced player has over newbies.

Smurfing won't get you banned as long as you don't violate the terms of service while playing.
If you don't want to discourage new players but also really want to smurf, play supporting champs/gods/heroes/... and try to hold back. Give tips, don't steamroll over them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat new to Smite, having a level 7 account now. I had went 25-8 in a Joust game, where my teammates weren't very good with their gods and I was basically carrying. We ended up losing that game, however when we got back to the match lobby, the other team started whining at me, calling me very hurtful names and accusing me of Smurfing. They reported me and basically ruined my day.

What I'm trying to say is don't just assume that someone is Smurfing just because they're doing very well in the lower levels. In fact you shouldn't accuse someone at all. Just ignore it and move on.